# SQLite Query SET variable on a single row

Tags: mysql, sqlite, row, identity-column

I have a table called "allarmi_ingressi" in SQLite, with a lot of rows in it. 
I want to create a query that changes the variable on my column "visto" to 1, if "visto=0", and to 0, if "visto=1".
This is what i made:

```
UPDATE allarmi_ingressi SET visto = '1' WHERE visto = '0'
```

Of course this modify every row in the column "visto";

I want to know if it's possible to modify it "selecting" it by the primary key, in my case "id_allarme".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a SELECT query, you would use the WHERE clause to find rows with a specific `id_allarme` value.

The same WHERE clause can be used with UPDATE:

```
UPDATE allarmi_ingressi
SET visto = 1 - visto
WHERE id_allarme = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[CASE Expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case)</kbd>

**Query**

```
update allarmi_ingressi 
set visto = (
    case visto when '1' then '0'
    when '0' then '1'
    else visto end
)
where id_allarme = __; -- id here
```

Comment: I guess the "single row".

Comment: Thanks for the answer because it could be usefull, but I think this changes all columns as  my old query, and not a single one, as i want.